# Using powershell to edit multiple XML files

Tags: powershell, powershell-1.0

How can I get a list of multiple XML files from a specified directory and for each file add an element under the second root node using powershell?

Example:
I want to add `<LastName>SomeName</LastName>` within the FIRST `<Names>` element:

```
<People>
  <Names>
      <FirstName>someFirstName</FirstName>
  </Names>
  <Names>
      <FirstName>myFirstName</FirstName>
      <Address>SomeAddress</Address>
  </Names>
</People>
```

Will become:

```
<People>
  <Names>
      <LastName>SomeName</LastName>
      <FirstName>someFirstName</FirstName>
  </Names>
  <Names>
      <FirstName>myFirstName</FirstName>
      <Address>SomeAddress</Address>
  </Names>
</People>
```

Comment: is powershell the only tool you can use?

Comment: Nope, powershell is not the only tool I could use. Just thought that it would be the easiest to use. Can you recommend anything else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it using `CreateElement` and `AppendChild` method

```
Get-ChildItem c:\temp\ *.xml | 
    % { 
        $xml      = [xml](Get-Content $_.fullname)
        $lastName = $xml.CreateElement('LastName')
        $lastName.PsBase.InnerText = 'SomeName'
        $null     = $xml.People.Names[0].AppendChild($lastName)
        $xml.Save($_.FullName)
    }
```

In case that you run PowerShell V2, you don't need to use property `PsBase`:

```
        $lastName.InnerText = 'SomeName'
```

There are for sure other ways, but this is one is quite easy.

---

In case that the node would be deeper in xml, you might use Xpath like this (both find first `Names` node):

```
$node = (Select-Xml -Xml $x -XPath '//Names[1]').Node
$node = (Select-Xml -Xml $x -XPath '//Names[position()=1]').Node
```

Comment: Erm, you should really get rid of that line mentioning regular expressions in this answer. We've been down that road many tmies before here on SO—it's *not* an option when processing XML.

Comment: Done. Agree with you but for some users this could be option. I could even replace first occurence of `</FirstName>` with `</FirstName><LastName>SomeName</LastName>` and then reformat it as xml. *Hack*

Comment: I get this error when running the script:
"Property 'InnerText' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable."

Could it be my version of Powershell?

Comment: If you add `$lastName.GetType().FullName`, what does it return? Also you might try `$lastName.PsBase.InnerText=..`. There were some issues in V1, although I assumed that the proposed solution should work well.

Comment: Great. Adding PsBase worked :) But what does it do? Also, how would I remove the xmlns attribute which was added to the element? Adding $lastName.GetType().FullName returns System.Xml.XmlElement

Comment: The workaround with `PsBase` is because powerShell wrapps all the objects into own object (`PSObject`) and sometimes it didn't work properly. `PsBase` is the original object. Do you really need to remove xmlns attr? Because in V2 there is none. Don't you want to switch to V2? Higly recommended! ;)